# Populate a drop-down menu based on two other drop-down menu items selected using a Google Web App

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am trying to populate a drop-down menu based on two separate selections from the user from two different drop-downs (1. Select Department, 2. Select Level) in order to populate the third drop-down menu with corresponding options (Project name) that will be pulled from the third column in a Google Sheet. Struggling with trying to comparing two html elements to determine the third element. I start getting lost in the different levels of the code from connecting front end functions from server side functions.

**HTML Code**

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select id="departments"  required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select your Department</option>
          <option>Department A</option>
          <option>Department B</option>
          <option>Department C</option>
          <option>Department D</option>
          <option>Department E</option> 
          <option>Department F</option>
        </select>      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select id="level" required>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Level</option>
          <option>1</option>
          <option>2</option>
          <option>3</option>
          <option>4</option>
        </select>      
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="input-field col s6">
        <select id="project" name="selectedProject" required>
        </select>
     </div>
  </div>     <div class="row">
      <button id="btn" class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large">Submit<i class="material-icons left">inbox</i></button>
   </div> 
</body>
```

**Javascript**

```
function getProjectName(department, level){
  var url = "url link to spreadsheet";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("projects");
  var data = ws.getRange(1,1).getDataRange.getValues();

  
  var projectOptions = {};
 
  data.forEach(function(value){    
    projectOptions[value[2]] = null;        
  });

  return projectOptions;
 
}



 function populateProjects(codes){
    
     const elm = document.getElementById('project');
     const code = listCodes
       .map(row => `<option value="${row}">${row}</option>`)
      .join('');
      
      elm.innerHTML =
      '<option disabled selected>Select Project Code</option>' + code;
    setTimeout(() => M.FormSelect.init(elm), 0);
    }
<script>
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",collectForm);


google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateProjects).getProjectName(department, level); 

*** need function to get both selections from both drop-down menus on change
function filterSelections(){

document.getElementById("department").addEventListener("change", ????);
document.getElementById("level").addEventListener("change", ????);
```

//I don't know how to filter and map these two selections to run a function to populate the third drop-down menu.
}

**Spreadsheet Data**
|Department |   Level   | Project |
|Department A|  1|  AP01|
|Department A|  2|  AP02|
|Department A|  3|  AP03|
|Department A|  4|  AP04|
|Department A|  3|  AP03|
|Department B|  4|  BP04|
|Department B|  2|  BP02|
|Department B|  1|  AP01|
|Department B|  3|  BP03|
|Department B|  2|  BP02|
|Department C|  3|  CP03|
|Department C|  2|  CP02|
|Department C|  1|  AP01|
|Department C|  4|  CP04|
|Department C|  1|  AP01|
|Department D|  2|  DP02|
|Department D|  1|  AP01|
|Department D|  3|  DP03|
|Department D|  4|  DP04|
|Department D|  4|  DP04|
|Department E|  1|  EP01|
|Department E|  2|  EP02|
|Department E|  3|  EP03|
|Department E|  4|  EP04|
|Department E|  4|  EP04|
|Department F|  2|  FP02|
|Department F|  1|  AP01|
|Department F|  4|  FP04|
|Department F|  3|  FP03|
|Department F|  2|  FP02|

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you get your data from the spreadsheet into an array of objects like this:

```
 const data = [
    {
      department: 'Department A',
      level: '1',
      project: 'AP01'
    },
    {
      department: 'Department A',
      level: '1',
      project: 'AP02'
    },
    {
      department: 'Department A',
      level: '2',
      project: 'AP02'
    },
    {
      department: 'Department A',
      level: '3',
      project: 'AP03'
    },
    {
      department: 'Department A',
      level: '4',
      project: 'AP04'
    },
    {
      department: 'Department B',
      level: '1',
      project: 'BP01'
    },
    {
      department: 'Department B',
      level: '2',
      project: 'BP02'
    },
    {
      department: 'Department B',
      level: '3',
      project: 'BP03'
    },
  ]
```

Then you could do this:

```
      const department = document.getElementById('departments');
      const level = document.getElementById('level');
      const project = document.getElementById('project');

      function populate(){
        const selectedDepartment = department.value;
        const selectedLevel = level.value;
        const projects = [];

        for(row of data){
          if(row.department === selectedDepartment && row.level === selectedLevel){
            projects.push(row.project);
          }
        }

        while (project.firstChild) {
          project.removeChild(project.lastChild);
        }
        projects.forEach(p => {
          let projectOption = document.createElement('option');
          projectOption.textContent = p;
          project.appendChild(projectOption);
        });

      }
  department.addEventListener('change', populate);
  level.addEventListener('change', populate);
```

This will populate the third dropdown every time one of the first two dropdowns changes.

You can see it working here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h01q24eu/2/)

Comment: Thanks @clod9353. I am not using an array of objects, I would be pulling the data from a Google Spreadsheet. Your jsfiddle doesn't populate the project drop-down menu?

Answer (score 0):

*First a markdown tip - to get your spreadsheet data on a new line you should add in two spaces after the line.*
*What is the `***` in your JavaScript? I assume this was just a typo in trying to write a comment*

#### Server-side vs Client-side

I assume that the JavaScript posted is the server-side script. That is, the Apps Script. You are trying to run *all* the code in the server-side script whereas you need to run some of it on the client-side.

- `<script>` tags, `getElementById` and `google.script.run` don't belong there, these need to be within the HTML file, that is, client-side. So your HTML file would look something like this:

```html
<body>
<!--
...
-->
</body>
<script>
    function populate(){
        let department = document
                            .getElementById("departments")
                            .textContent // or some way to get value
        let level = document
                            .getElementById("level")
                            .textContent // or some way to get value
                            
        // Define server-side function to take these values
        // and return a list of values to use for the `project` drop down.
        
        let valuesToPopulate = google.script.run.yourFunction(department, level) 
        
        valuesToPopulate.forEach(value =>{
            // Build the options for the drop down
            })
    }
    
    function collectForm(){
        let project = document
                        .getElementById("project")
                        .textContent // or some way to get the value
    
        google.script.run // call server-side with this value
        }
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",collectForm);
    document.getElementById("department").addEventListener("change", populate);
    document.getElementById("level").addEventListener("change", populate);
    
    
     
</script>
```

When passing a function to `addEventListener`, you can't call the server-side Apps Script code from there. You need to define a separate function that contains a `google.script.run`.

Think of Apps Script, that is, everything that is `SpreadsheetApp` or similar, goes in server-side. JavaScript, i.e. `document.getElementById` or `addEventListener` belongs on the client-side, i.e. in the `HTML` file in your script editor.

#### References

- [Guide to client-to-server communication](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)
- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)